# User Authorization After Logging Into Google SHOPIFY

Tags: php, laravel, shopify

I can't find information about the user's authorization account anywhere after logging into Google. I have a code, an application on laravel, which logs in to Google, after logging in, we receive the user's email, token, etc., how do we authorize customers to the account in the store?

Im googling and found nothing

Answer (score 1):

If you mean, where is the SSO, you have to be on the Plus plan to use SSO. So once you authenticate into your Google, you can pass a payload to your SSO service connected to Shopify, and it takes care of logging in your authenticated User.

Comment: I can make this without some plugins?

Comment: You can only login to Plus stores. No need for plugins.